# How to save multiple individual records for a single model

Tags: cakephp, model, save

I have a model(friends), where user can export his friend's info from facebook. I want save friends info(id and name) into the mysql database.

I am having trouble creating a form for the same using form helper as i don't know the exact number of friends for each user.

Is there a easier way to save user's friends into the database? (save multiple records for the same model)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should know how much is the number of friends for the current user, right?

If so, do a loop with following in your view:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
for($i=0;$i<$number_of_current_user_friends;$i++){
  echo $this->Form->input('Friend.'.$i.'user_id', array('value'=>$current_user_id));
  echo $this->Form->input('Friend.'.$i.'friend_name', array('value'=>$friends[$i]['name']));
  echo $this->Form->input('Friend.'.$i.'fb_id', array('value'=>$friends[$i]['fb_id']));
}
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

then in the controller save it with:

```
$this->Friend->saveAll($this->data);
```

Comment: shouldnt it be echo $this->Form->input('Friend.'.$i.'.user_id',array('value'=>$current_user_id));